# Accessing internal calculations of Mathematica code

Tags: integer-sequence

For a given Mathematica program that generates a sequence x of integers, is it possible to also generate equal length sequences of integers that were used internally by the Mathematica kernel to generate x?

For example for an OEIS sequence: oeis.org/A052104, the Mathematica code on that page has a formula that creates the integer sequence for A052104, internally the Mathematica kernel would also create other integer sequences to generate the A052104 sequence, ie there is a term in the formula m!/n!, so there should be three integer sequences: m!, n! and m!/n! that are used internally by the Mathematica kernel. I'd like a way to have a list of all the integer sequences and their formulas.

Comment: I've read this five times. I still have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: updated the question with an example

Comment: Look at `Reap` and `Sow`, use them to enclose the terms you're interested in...

Comment: I was hoping for an automatic way to do it, ie to process all OEIS sequences that have Mathematica code.

Comment: Unfortunately, the state of computer code in OEIS is not consistent. There is no way to automatically process OEIS sequence code the way you describe.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is asking for functionality that is not supported given the constraints the OP is putting on the solution.

Comment: Wrapping the code with `Trace` and processing it further might yield what you seek for.